# How to make Sidebar Hidden when page loads up in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my [website](http://clickdesti.netne.net/) .
It has a top menu and a sidebar menu. When the page loads up, the side bar is by default visible. There is no problem in Desktop, but when this is viewed on Mobile device, the side bar comes above the content of the website and it is not possible to remove it, since the toggle button to show/hide it is in the top menu.

Is it possible to make it hidden by default when the page loads up ? (Problem 1)

Also, if it works, then the show/hide sidebar works fine in desktop, but if we minimize the brower window, it becomes opposite, like, when it is hidden, HIDE SIDEBAR is displayed, when it is shown, SHOW SIDEBAR is displayed.

The jquery code I used to Hide/Show side bar is:

```
 var f=1; // to displayd HIDE, since by default its shown.
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(){
    if (f==0)
        {
            $("#menu-toggle").html("<b>Show Categories</b>");
            f=1;
        }
    else
        {
            $("#menu-toggle").html("<b>Hide Categories</b>");
            f=0;
        }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to know if I am on mobile or desktop, so that I can initialise the value of f accordingly? (Problem 2)

Comment: i would completely do that with media queries. Make two variants of `#menu-toggle` and show/ hide each respectively in css

Answer (score 2):

Add one more line in `$(document).ready` to `trigger click` event on `page load` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Event code start here
       ....
    //Event code end here
    $("#menu-toggle").trigger('click') //trigger its click
});
```

> For your 2nd problem you will get lot of `javascript` solutions if you
>   search, like one **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)** and **[another here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)**

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works, but that problem, when i view this website on mobile device, that black area above all my content still exists, any idea why is it there? ( Please view [this](http://clickdesti.netne.net/) website from your mobile device to get the problem.

Comment: @BaqirKhan You are toggling whole `div - #wrapper` which covers whole body contents inside it.. try separating concerns for sidebar and remaining part of body..

Comment: ok, I did what u say, #wrapper has the side menu and rest body is seprated, but now when menu is toggled on..it overlaps the content of the body.

Comment: You are just doing `padding-left` and `hiding` and `showing` the element right? Also add one more property to `#wrapper display:none`

Comment: Yes I m using margin left and padding-left. However, it doesnt seem to work, in mobile, it still shows that big black scree.:(  i will try to figure it out,Thank you anyway for the help so far :)

Comment: No probs.. Not getting proper idea to give perfect solution.. Sorry for that.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

using toggle will be more convenient than click,if u want to make it hidden when the page loads up ,set display none first in html(simple way)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#menu-toggle").toggle(function(){
     if($(this).css('display') === 'none')
    {
        $("#menu-toggle").html("<b>Hide Categories</b>"); //this is hide
    }
 else
    {
        $("#menu-toggle").html("<b>Show Categories</b>"); //this is show
    }
 });
 });
```